# I am trying to model the electric force in Python, but the force always seems to repel

Tags: python, simulation, physics

**Edit:** Sorry, I didn't think about writing tests. I will do so, and see if I can't find out what I've done wrong. Thanks to the person who suggested I write tests!

I am trying to write a computer simulation in Python that simulates the electric force and how atoms interact with it. For those that don't know, essentially, things with opposite (positive and negative) charges attract, and like charges repel, and the magnitude of the force falls of as 1 / (distance squared). I try placing a negatively charged particle (oxygen ion) and a positive charged particle (hydrogen ion) into a coordinate system, and expect them to attract, and move closer together, but instead they alawys repel! Naturally, I thought it must just have been a typo, so I added a negative sign to my model of the eletric force, but they still repel! I have no idea what's going on, and was hoping some of you folks might have a clue as to what's going wrong here. Below is the code. I've included everything so that you can just run it from your own terminal to see for yourselves what happens.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

Å = 10 ** (-10)
u = 1.660539040 * (10 ** (-27))
k = 8.987551787368 * (10 ** 9)
e = 1.6021766208 * (10 ** (-19))

hydrogen1 = dict(
    name='Hydrogen 1',
    charge=1 * e,
    mass=1.00793 * u,
    position=[0.5 * Å, 0.5 * Å, 0.5 * Å],
    velocity=[0, 0, 0],
    acceleration=[0, 0, 0],
    force=[0, 0, 0]
)
oxygen1 = dict(
    name='Oxygen 1',
    charge=-2 * e,
    mass=15.9994 * u,
    position=[0, 0, 0],
    velocity=[0, 0, 0],
    acceleration=[0, 0, 0],
    force=[0, 0, 0]
)

atoms = [hydrogen1, oxygen1]


def magnitude(vector):
    magnitude = 0
    for coordinate in vector:
        magnitude += (coordinate ** 2)
    return math.sqrt(magnitude)


def scale_vector(vector, scalefactor):
    scaled_vector = vector
    i = 0
    while i < len(vector):
        vector[i] *= scalefactor
        i += 1
    return scaled_vector


def sum_vectors(vectors):
    resultant_vector = [0, 0, 0]
    for vector in vectors:
        i = 0
        while i < len(vector):
            resultant_vector[i] += vector[i]
            i += 1
    return resultant_vector


def distance_vector(point1, point2):
    if type(point1) is list and type(point2) is list:
        pos1 = point1
        pos2 = point2
    elif type(point1) is dict and type(point2) is dict:
        pos1 = point1['position']
        pos2 = point2['position']
    vector = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(pos1):
        vector.append(pos2[i] - pos1[i])
        i += 1
    return vector


def distance(point1, point2):
    return magnitude(distance_vector(point1, point2))


def direction_vector(point1, point2):
    vector = distance_vector(point1, point2)
    length = magnitude(vector)
    return scale_vector(vector, 1 / length)


def eletric_force(obj1, obj2):
    length = k * obj1['charge'] * \
        obj2['charge'] / ((distance(obj1, obj2)) ** 2)
    force_vector = scale_vector(direction_vector(obj1, obj2), length)
    return force_vector


def force_to_acceleration(force, mass):
    scalefactor = 1 / (mass)
    return scale_vector(force, scalefactor)


time = 10

t = 0
period = 1 / 1000

while t < time:
    i = 0
    while i < len(atoms):
        atom = atoms[i]
        position = atom['position']
        velocity = atom['velocity']
        acceleration = atom['acceleration']

        # Moving the atom
        atom['position'] = sum_vectors(
            [position, scale_vector(velocity, period)])

        # Accelerating the atom using its current acceleration vector
        atom['velocity'] = sum_vectors([
            velocity, scale_vector(acceleration, period)])

        # Calculating the net force on the atom
        force = [0, 0, 0]
        j = 0
        while j < len(atoms):
            if j != i:
                force = sum_vectors([force, eletric_force(atoms[i], atoms[j])])
            j += 1

        # Updating the force and acceleration on the atom
        atoms[i]['force'] = [force[0], force[1], force[2]]
        atom['acceleration'] = force_to_acceleration(
            [force[0], force[1], force[2]], atom['mass'])

        i += 1

    t += period

np.random.seed(19680801)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for atom in atoms:
    name = atom['name']
    position = atom['position']
    X = position[0]
    Y = position[1]
    Z = position[2]
    print(
        f'Position of {name}: [{X}, {Y}, {Z}]')
    color = 'green'
    if 'Oxygen' in atom['name']:
        color = 'red'
    ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, color=color)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

Below are the tests:

```
from functions import *
from constants import *
from atoms import hydrogen1, hydrogen2, oxygen1
import math


def test_magnitude():
    assert magnitude({1, 3, -5}) == math.sqrt(35)


def test_sum_vectors():
    assert sum_vectors([[1, 2, 3], [0, -4, 8]]) == [1, -2, 11]


def test_scale_vector():
    assert scale_vector([1, 4, -3], -2) == [-2, -8, 6]


def test_distance_vector():
    assert distance_vector([1, 4, 3], [0, 1, 1]) == [-1, -3, -2]
    assert distance_vector(hydrogen2, hydrogen1) == [Å, Å, Å]


def test_distance():
    assert distance([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]) == math.sqrt(8)
    assert distance(hydrogen1, oxygen1) == math.sqrt(0.75) * Å
    assert distance(hydrogen1, hydrogen2) == Å * math.sqrt(3)


def test_direction_vector():
    assert direction_vector([1, 1, 1], [7, 5, -3]) == [6 /
                                                       math.sqrt(68), 4 / math.sqrt(68), -4 / math.sqrt(68)]
    m = 1 / math.sqrt(3)
    for component in direction_vector(hydrogen2, hydrogen1):
        assert abs(component - m) < 10 ** (-12)


def test_electric_force():
    m = 4.439972744 * 10 ** (-9)
    for component in electric_force(hydrogen1, hydrogen2):
        assert abs(component - m) < 10 ** (-12)


def test_force_to_acceleration():
    assert force_to_acceleration(
        [4, 3, -1], 5.43) == [4 / 5.43, 3 / 5.43, -1 / 5.43]
```

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is that `magnitude([1,1,1])` returns 3.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realise I forgot to take the square root when calculating magnitude. I fixed that, but I still get the same problem.

Comment: The point I'd like to make is that you need to write tests for your code. You hand-wrote this vector math instead of using a library; you need to make sure it's all working (and clearly it isn't or you wouldn't be here). Asking random people on the internet for eyeball checks isn't a replacement for unit tests.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Yeah, I didn't think of that. I'll have to write some tests then. Thanks!

Comment: I've now written tests for the code, and all the functions seem to be working correctly. Can anyone see why they don't play nice together? I have included the tests in the post above.

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate electric charge, you take your direction vector, which is pointing to the partner atom, and multiply it by a negative number (because your mismatched charges give a negative product), which results in a force vector pointing away from your partner atom.

You should also consider the risks of doing this modeling with these numbers (the epsilon for floats is somewhere around `1e-16`). If you intend you model on angstrom scales, it might be best to go with angstroms as your unit. If you intend to model on meter scales you might want to stick with what you have. Just be careful rescaling your constants.

The direction vector is the code problem, and if you fix that you get your next problem; at `t=0`, your atoms in your example have an acceleration of `2e19`, and at the first point after `t=0`, they have a velocity of `2e16` (which, assuming I have your units right, is a bunch of orders of magnitude faster than the speed of light). They move so fast that they rocket toward and then past each other, and then the inverse square distance force of electrostatics functionally goes to 0 after the second tick and they'll never slow down from their hyperwarp.

There are options to deal with this; shorter ticks (femtoseconds?), changing to a relativistic velocity calculation, etc. You could also try modeling with a continuous curve instead of discrete points, but that will fall down so fast if you try to scale it to more than a couple atoms... ultimately this is just a core problem of physics modeling. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try modelling with angstroms and see if that makes a difference. However, I don't think the direction vector is the problem. If it was, I would expect to be able to insert a negative somewhere, e.g in calculating the force or the direction vector, and then they should attract, but this is not the case. Even when I add a negative sign, they still repel.

Comment: The direction of your force vector is your code problem. Your next problem is more conceptual; I've edited the answer to include it.